# Filter with timestamp not filtering data R

Tags: r

I have a large dataset (67000 obs, 6 vars) that I am trying to filter using an associated timestamp. I am using the `dplyr::filter` function and while some rows are being removed from the dataset, it is not behaving as I would expect. See below:

Example data

```
timestamp     Var2      Var3
12.58.00      0.0       1.2
12.58.10      0.1       1.5
12.58.20      0.2       1.3
...
2.49.50       6719.79   1.37
2.49.60       6719.89   1.20
2.49.70       6719.99   1.14
```

Script with `filter` call:

```
data <- read_excel("file.xlsx", col_names = TRUE)
data$timestamp <- sapply(strsplit(data$timestamp, split = " ", fixed = TRUE), function(x) (x[2]))
data$timestamp <- str_replace_all(data$timestamp, ":", ".")
  
data <- filter(data, data$timestamp > "1.29.00" & data$timestamp < "2.51.00")
```

Expected outcome:

```
timestamp     Var2       Var3
1.29.00       1870.9     1.3
1.29.10       1871.0     1.5
1.29.20       1871.1     0.7
...
2.49.50       6719.79   1.37
2.49.60       6719.89   1.20
2.49.70       6719.99   1.14
```

Instead of the expected outcome, I am getting a dataframe which included rows with timestamp:

12.58.00-12.59.59

then the next row is:

1.29.11

What in my call of `filter` is not working as I think it should? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing strings. To compare time, convert `timestamp` to `POSIXct` or similar.

```
df$t1 <- as.POSIXct(df$timestamp, format = '%H.%M.%S')
start <- as.POSIXct("1.29.00", format = '%H.%M.%S')
end <- as.POSIXct("2.51.00", format = '%H.%M.%S')

subset(df, t1 > start & t1 < end)
```

Or using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(between(t1, start, end))
```

Comment: That's great, I didn't think of data class, thanks a bunch